# What is the `Rmch-Securitycookie` HTTP header?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, http-headers

I'm seeing some weird POST errors to my Rails 5 site. They are in the form of `POST https://www.example.com/pages/:5054`, with the weird `:5054` at the end. I also do not have any route that POSTs to `/pages/` or `/pages/:id`. I've got no idea what is causing these weird POSTs. The referrer-URLs are from my site, so it is not, as far as I can see, some weird bot or some such.

The only common denominator I see is the presence of the `Rmch-Securitycookie:` header on the bad requests. While I do not know if this is the root cause of my issue, it's a start at least. I'm thinking it's a bad extension or some monitoring software or some such. Google turns up nothing; has anyone encountered this header and knows what it is?

Comment: Did you find out the cause of this? I'm seeing it in one of our .NET applications so I don't think it's strictly related to RoR

Comment: Sadly no, I did not :(.